# Python Selenium - Button not clicking

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

AIM:  **Refresh until button is clickable**

Hi there, I have been desperately trying to get this code working with very little success.  The webpage refreshes whether the button is visible or not.  I have tried various methods such as using **by class** (Button__StyledButton-iESSlv dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy) and I am now trying **by text**

Any help would be appreciated as I am going mad trying to get this working.  Thank you

```
<div data-component="add-to-basket-button-wrapper" class="space-b center" data-fupid="10219839" data-button-label="
                            Add to basket
            ">

<button class="Button__StyledButton-iESSlv dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy">
<span class="Icon__Wrapper-dxArjw eWWxFk dc-icon dc-icon-add-to-basket Icon-cinbSj sc-kHNMoK eibtOA YuGGQ" rotate="0" data-name="AddToBasket"></path></svg></span> 
                            Add to basket
            </button></div>
```

```
print ("opening webpage")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get(page)

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Add to basket']").click()
            break
        except:
            driver.refresh()
        continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you provide the page. Seeams that thext that you are looking for is not under button node, so you can try something else, but for more help provide site or more HTML

Comment: I am trying this test page here - https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/home-appliances/floorcare/vacuum-cleaners/dyson-v11-outsize-cordless-vacuum-cleaner-red-10219839-pdt.html

Comment: Great sou you can use findelements which will return multiple elements and  CSS selector  (".Button__StyledButton-iESSlv.dJJJCD") and you need a first from that list. It is a method "find_elements_by_css_selector(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.Button__StyledButton-iESSlv.dJJJCD'))

Comment: do you mean this? - driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Button__StyledButton-iESSlv.dJJJCD").click() - I tried it and it still never worked

Comment: eleements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.Button__StyledButton-iESSlv.dJJJCD')) it is this and after you need to get first element from elements. Also put browser sleep before you reach for the button, just to make sure that your element is present in DOM. If that helps, you will need to use expected conditions.

Comment: use time.sleep(10) as first line in try block, and change the selector to css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I'm seeing is that your locator doesn't locate any elements on the page. You can test your locator on the page in the Chrome devtools by running `$x()` for XPath and `$$()` for CSS selectors. In your example, you would run `$x("//button[text() = 'Add to basket']")` and see that it returns 0 (an empty set).

Another issue you would have run into is that there are two "Add to basket" buttons. There's one in the touch portion of the page (I'm assuming for mobile/tablet layout) and the one that you want. The one you want is the second one in the DOM so we need to find a way to create a locator that is unique to the right one. To do this, we can add a DIV with id = "product-actions" to the locator. Now try `$$("#product-actions span[data-name='AddToBasket']")` and see that it returns 1. Now we need to add a wait to make sure that the page is loaded properly before trying to click this element. Here's the updated code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
print ("opening webpage")
driver.get(page)

def main():
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#product-actions span[data-name='AddToBasket']"))).click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I type that line into devtools it returns [span.Icon__Wrapper-dxArjw.eWWxFk.dc-icon.dc-icon-add-to-basket.Icon-cinbSj.sc-kHNMoK.eibtOA.YuGGQ] - but when I run the code it still doesn't click the button

Comment: I eventually got it... I had to use execute script to click the button